# Query a column in a data extension with multiple values

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I need to join the ProdutID from this Data Extension with another one from a different DE.

Is there a way to do that considering that I have multiple values/fields under one column?

[image]

Comment: You likely would have to use a subquery to parse out the XML into a table format for you to then reference in your main query. This would likely be a TON of processing. You may want to break this into multiple queries or steps.

Comment: thanks, would you be able to give me an example of a subquery please

Comment: `SELECT a.* FROM ( SELECT b.* FROM [de] b WHERE a.x = b.x ) a`

Comment: @Gortonington what am I doing wrong? SELECT a.ProductId FROM ( SELECT b.OrderLines FROM [data extension name] b WHERE a.ProductId = b.OrderLines ) a

Comment: you need to parse the xml in the subquery. Check out this post from SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352323/parse-xml-using-t-sql-and-xquery-searching-for-specific-values)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the SFMC SQL won't allow you to parse the XML.

Fortunately, you can brute-force your way by using SUBSTRING (if XML structure is static - more in [MS T-SQL Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) or CHARINDEX with LEFT/RIGHT (if it is dynamic - more in [my SFMC SQL Docs](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-string-functions#charindex)) on the column with text. Use the function directly within JOIN/ON.

```
LEFT JOIN columnB b ON a.Value = SUBSTRING(b.Value, 5, 10)
```

It might, however, slow down your query. Be cautious of AutoKill.